# How to easily make labels for stacked area charts in R like in D3plus

Tags: r, area, stacked, d3plus

D3plus automatically shrinks and arranges labels for stacked area plots. Is it possible to do the same in R?

I understand that there is a D3Plus package for R but before I walk through their code, I want to be sure that no one has already created a helper function to do this natively. [Here is a link to the D3plus code](https://d3plus.org/examples/basic/9029462/) and below are two examples. [image]